# Outlook 2013 (connected to imap accounts) with mandatory profiles on Server 2012R2 RDS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, outlook, remote-desktop-services, rds, microsoft-office

Windows 2012R2 RDS and Outlook 2013. Mandatory Profiles with folder redirection to users Homefolders.

Anyone have any ideas on using outlook (connected to imap mail accounts) with mandatory profiles. I have a group policy to point the data file to the users home folders and even tried redirecting appdata (only does roaming appdata) but still after each new clean login outlook prompts to be configured and loses its settings. Any thoughts welcomed..